# Express - Wrapping controller functions with try-catch

Tags: node.js, express, try-catch

I have an express backend application. The problem I have is that all the routes contains the same try-catch piece which causes code bloat in my program:

```
// routes.js
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = extractData(req)
    await foo(data)
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})

// controllers.js
async function foo(data) {...do smh}
```

As you see above, `try { extractData() } catch (err) { next(err) }` portion of the code exists in all of the routes defined in the app.

I tried to create a wrapper function that takes controller function as parameter and use it as:

```
// routes.js
router.get('/', controllerWrapper(req, res, next, foo))

// controller-wrapper.js
async function controllerWrapper(req, res, next, controllerFunc) {
  try {
    const data = extractData(req)
    await controllerFunc(data)
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
}
```

But this does not work due to function being invoked, and not being actually a callback.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a closure for this, so you can return the middleware function from `controllerWrapper` and use the `controllerFunc` inside the returned middleware

```
function controllerWrapper(controllerFunc) {
      return async function (req, res, next) {
          try {
              const data = extractData(req)
              await controllerFunc(data)
          } catch (err) {
             next(err)
          }
      }
}


router.get('/', controllerWrapper(foo))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default error middleware handler provide by express to be use for prevent try catch every route

```
const app: Application = express();
export function ResponseErrorHandler(error: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
}
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
});
//app.use(router);
app.use(ResponseErrorHandler);
```